# php not working shows blank page

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm developing an Android app with remote access Database, so I used PHP to connect with mySQL database . However , My php code shows blank page and I could not find the reason ,  please any help will be appreciated ..

```
<?php


// include db connect class
require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';
$response = array();
$groupname = array();
$response["Groups"]=array();
//if (isset($_POST['FID5'])){

//$FID = $_POST['FID5'] ;


$FID = '6';// here im just for testing it
  if($FID == '6'){


$db = new DB_CONNECT();
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
// get all classrooms from classroom clinic table
$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `facultymanagegroup` WHERE FID =         '$FID'");
if (mysql_num_rows($result1)>0) {
while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {
$groupid = $row1['GroupID'];

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `group` where GroupType= 'Course Group'      AND GroupID = '$groupid' ");
if (mysql_num_rows($result)>0) {
while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
   $Group = array();
   $Group["GroupID"] = $row2["GroupID"];
   $Group["GroupName"] = $row2["GroupName"];
    $Group["GroupType"] = $row2["GroupType"];

     $groupn = $row2["GroupID"];
     array_push($groupname, $groupn);

    array_push($response["Groups"], $Group);}}
    }}


$result3 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `group` where GroupType= 'Course  Group' AND fID = '$FID'");
if($result3 === FALSE) { 
die(mysql_error()); // TODO: better error handling
}

// check for empty result
if (mysql_num_rows($result3)>0) {
// looping through all results
// classroom node
while ($row4 = mysql_fetch_array($result3)) {
    // temp user array
 for ($i = 0; $i < count($groupname); ++$i) {   

    $Group = array();
    $Group["GroupID"] = $row4["GroupID"];
    $Group["GroupName"] = $row4["GroupName"];
    $Group["GroupType"] = $row4["GroupType"];
    if($groupname[$i] == $row4["GroupID"]; ){
    $ok = 0 ;
    Break;
   }
   else{
   $ok = 1 ;
}}
if($ok == 1){
      array_push($response["Groups"], $Group);

}   
}
// success
$response['success'] = 1;

// echoing JSON response
} else {
// no classrooms found
$response['success'] = 0;
$response['message'] = 'No faculty members found';
}}
else {
// no classrooms found
$response["success"] = 0;
$response["message"] = "Not setted";

// echo no users JSON

}


// echo no users JSON
echo json_encode($response);

?>
```

Comment: (during debugging/development) enable error reporting at the top of your script:  ``error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);``

Comment: Syntax error: `if($groupname[$i] == $row4["GroupID"]; ){`- Semicolon inside parenthesis. Also, turn on erroring as suggested by @fbas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May not solve the issue but fyi-

```
$result3 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `group` where ... fID = '$FID'");
```

you have fID instead of FID- the lowercase f will throw your query off.

Comment: no idea why this was accepted. it doesn't cover the entire issues. should comments be deleted, would render this answer misleading

Comment: I don't know , but that answer just solved my problem.

Comment: If error reporting was turned on instead of a blank page there probably would have been an error listed. 

Syntax errors can cause pages to stop loading and processing the rest of the file.

Comment: @Sarah you mean to say that this `if($groupname[$i] == $row4["GroupID"]; )` has no bearing on the issue at all? If so, I find that rather hard to believe. That semi-colon's an end of statement character.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, I understand your reputation yet I feel as though you're badgering at this because I posted a partial answer to the.... Answer section. You seem to be angered that, as a community, the issue was  solved. I didn't know I was required to restate all other corrections/partial answers already clearly listed on the page.

The correction you mention was, I'm sure, required... no need for passive aggression.  > 1 error may require > 1 correction. With the error messages disabled, she probably still received the blank page- until she saw my message and removed the lingering syntax error.